# K3 surfaces in Fano threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces, fano-varieties

By K3 surfaces and Fano threefolds, I mean smooth ones.

If a K3 surface $S$ is an anticanonical section of a Fano threefold $V$ of Picard rank one (hence, $Pic(V)=\mathbb Z H_V$ for some ample divisor $H_V$), then $h:=H_V|_S$ is a primitive ample divisor of $S$. A divisor class $h$ is said to be primitive if $h=nD$ for divisor class $D$ with $n\in \mathbb Z$ implies $n=\pm 1$.

According to the classification of Fano threefolds, $4 \le h^2 \le 22$.

My question is some converse of it:

> Let $S$ be a K3 surface with *very* ample primitive divisor $h$ ( $4 \le h^2 \le 22$). Then can $S$ be embedded into  a Fano threefold $V$ of Picard rank one  such that $h=H_V|_S$?

If $h^2=4, 6, 8$, the linear system $|h|$ embeds $S$ into projective spaces as a quartic surface, a complete intersection of quadric and cubic hypersurfaces and a complete intersection of three quadric hypersurfaces respectively. So the answer to the above question is yes in these cases.

But I am not sure about the cases of $h^2=10, 12, ..., 22$. Does anyone know the answer for any cases of those?

By the way, the answer is yes for *generic* K3 surfaces ([https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211313]) but I am wondering whether one can remove the condition `generic'.

Comment: For the locally free sheaf of principal parts on $V$, $\mathcal{P}^1_V(\omega_V)$, that occurs in the definition of the Atiyah extension, you can try to prove vanishing of $H^1(S,\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_V}(\mathcal{P}^1_V(\omega_V),\omega_V)|_S)$.  This would follow from vanishing of both $H^1(V,\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_V}(\mathcal{P}^1_V(\omega_V),\omega_V))$ and $H^2(V,\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_V}(\mathcal{P}^1_V(\omega_V),\omega_V)\otimes \omega_V)$.

Comment: To continue the previous comment, there is a short exact sequence by "contracting" with the class of the anticanonical section: $0\to H^{1,2}(V)\to H^1(V,T_V) \to H^1(S,\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_V}(\mathcal{P}^1(\omega_V),\omega_V)|_S) \to 0.$ So whenever the first map is surjective, then deformations of the polarized K3 arise from deformations as embedded anticanonical divisors in $V$.  Do you want to allow to deform $V$ as well as the divisor $S$ in the anticanonical linear system on $V$?

Comment: Now I understand what the OP is asking.  The computation in my comments shows that there is an *open* locus in the moduli stack of polarized K3 surfaces parameterizing those that embed as anticanonical divisors in some Fano threefold $V$.  I believe the OP is asking whether this open substack equals the entire moduli stack.  The answer is almost certainly "no" unless the Fano threefold $V$ is allowed to be singular or degenerate in some other way (e.g., allow the anticanonical divisor class to be $\mathbb{Q}$-big and nef).

Comment: It looks to me like $h^2=12$ gives counterexamples: some of these K3 surfaces are anticanonical divisors in the weighted projective threefold $V=\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,3)$.

Comment: There are smooth Fano threefolds with $H_V^3=12$ with index one.
Do you mean that the K3 surface in $P(1,1,1,3)$ cannot be embedded into any of those Fano threefolds?

Comment: I computed the intersection number $h^2$ incorrectly, sorry.  Anyway, now I see that this element $[S]$ of the linear series of $|\mathcal{O}(2)|$ on $V=\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,3)$ is actually a "hyperplane section" of an element $[V']$ of the linear series $|\mathcal{O}(2)|$ on $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,1,3)$, and this latter Fano threefold $V'$ is smooth (even though $V=\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,3)$ is a singular Fano threefold).  So these are examples of K3 surfaces that are divisors in a smooth Fano threefold (different from the singular Fano threefold we started with).